# prime divisors of the sum of two integers with given prime divisors

Tags: arithmetic, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, additive-combinatorics, goldbachs-conjecture

I want some results for the following statement.

> Let $S_{1}$, $S_{2}$, and $S_{3}$ be set of primes. There are infinitely many pairs of two integers $\left(m,n\right)$ such that (1) any prime divisor of $m$ is in $S_{1}$, (2) any prime divisor of $b$ is in $S_{2}$, and (3) any prime divisor of $m+n$ is in $S_{3}$.

You may give several conditions for $S_{i}$. For example, $S_{1}=S_{2}$, each $S_{i}$ is infinite, etc.

What are the suitable keywords to search problems like this statement?

Comment: If I were to attack that, I’d try playing around with numbers first. Maybe try a case where all three sets are singletons: each contains only one prime. This doesn’t look like a good candidate for getting the answer from somebody else, but what do I know?

Comment: If all $S_i$ are finite (and wlog equal to a single finite set $S$), then this is equivalent to the $S$-unit equation, to which there are only finitely many solutions.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thank you for your answer. Your answer may be a good clue. Is there a known condition of S for the equation to have a solution?

Comment: @Lubin         Your advice is right. Considering small simple example is a good starting point to consider the original problem. However, one among the sets $S_{i}$ should be infinite. If they are all finite, the union $S$ of sets $S_{i}$'s is finite. Then $S$-unit equation is weaker than my equation. Even $S$-unit equation has only finite solutions, but my equation has only finite solutions either.